# collapsing toolbar not hide all

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like to be able to do this I know it is a CollapsingToolbarLayout but I do not know how to make some idea stop at a distance, thanks for the help

[the result I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ma7m.png)

Comment: Check this project: https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of implementing a collapsing toolbar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/beach_scene"

            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
         app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sample_string"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Replace the image inside the ImageView as per your requirement which will be visible when the toolbar is expanded. 
Rest of the view can be implemented in the NestedScrollView as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to give below property to your `FloatingActionButton`

```
 app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
 app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
```

**Try something like this: almost similar to your requirements**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sample.foo.usingcoordinatorlayout.FabAndSnackbarActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:title="@string/collapsing_toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/long_latin"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/mascot_icon"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```